# Could not bind to 0.0.0.0:8080, it may be in use or require sudo

Tags: swift, vapor

Sometimes I get this error when trying to run a Vapor application from Xcode. Reopening Xcode doesn't help, only restarting of system do. Is it a bug of the framework? What should I do to prevent this?

Comment: did you check if anything was bound the port?

Comment: I'm sure it's previous instance of application is using the port. Because server on localhost is still working

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If using `sudo` does not fix this message, it means something is already bound to this port. It could be an instance of Vapor that didn't close correctly.

To fix this, you need to kill the previous instance. The easiest way to do this is:

```
lsof -i tcp:8080
```

Where `8080` is the port you are trying to use. This outputs something like:

```
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.apple 4679 tanner    8u  IPv4 0x890f6b0b31966939      0t0  TCP
```

Then kill the process bound to that port using its `PID`.

```
kill -9 4679
```

Comment: Great response. Thanks. It helps a lot.

Comment: Hi @Tanner I've tried given solution by you. But even after killing so many instances still getting same error. How to identify which instance need to kill? Any identification for instance?

Comment: @Hrishikesh check my answer

Comment: @AdamBardon Thank you so much... your answer help me a lot and its working now.

Answer (score 1):

While Tanner's answer should help in most cases, for me the `kill` command had no effect and no output. So I completely quitted & restarted terminal.
When running `lsof` there were no processes found anymore, and issue was solved.